# How can i know a number has a country code?

Tags: phone-number

I am using phone number for registration. System exact same as whatsapp.

1. User writes him number.
2. Server sends a sms to this number
3. User verifies his number.
4. Then user's adress book sends to server for find him friends.

Problem starts here. This will be an international app. You know every country has different phone number formats. I am gonna store all numbers like this: *123456789*

If user already put the country code to head of the number then there is no problem. But if he doesn't what should i do? How can i know a number has a country code? If i know it then i can put the country code of adress book's owner. Because if a number dont have a country code then they are living in the same country.

Comment: Make 2 separate inputs, one for country code and one for the actual number. That's probably the most universal solution of your problem

Comment: No i dont mean this.  I mean getting from adress book.(from contacts app)

Comment: Numbers with country code will begin with `+`, right?  Then having number that is not starting from `+` as users input you can do search in your numbers database to look for a number which starts with `+` and contains digits that came as an input in the same order as in input. If something is found - you join your input data to the search result. If not - you just save the input as a number without a country code.

Sorry if I misunderstood the problem.

Comment: But +905383708177 is same thing with 905383708177 so you can call both of them without a problem. So + is not silver bullet

Answer (score 0):

Use this snippet of code and remember to add libphonenumber 8.8.1 library:

```
//Get the International Code
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
PhoneNumberUtil mPhone = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
Phonenumber.PhoneNumber mNumber;

//Get the phone no
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usr_phone_no);
//Remove all 0's in the left and non-numeral characters and parse it to an international number format
String userPhoneNumber = Long.valueOf(editText.getText().toString().replaceAll("[^\\d]", "")).toString();
mNumber = mPhone.parse(userPhoneNumber, tm.getSimCountryIso().toUpperCase());

//Transform it the way you will use it (In this case, Long)
Long phoneNumber = Long.valueOf(String.format("%d%d",mNumber.getCountryCode(),mNumber.getNationalNumber()));
```